# Allow Spring to access beans defined in child module layer

Tags: java, spring, java-11, java-module

I have an application that has an interesting module architecture: it consists of own modules which in turn consist of jpms modules:

```
aplication (dependencies: spring.boot, spring.core, etc...)
|
+--module1 (dependencies: ...)
|
+--module2 (dependencies: ...)
```

1. Application and each module uses own `module layer`. In such hierarchy, modules can access classes from parent module (application).
2. Application and each module uses own Spring's `ApplicationContext`, and they have corresponding child-parent relations.

Spring works normally inside application, but can't access classes inside child modules because of another module layer. Spring begings its work by scanning for annotations on source classes passed through SpringApplicationBuilder#sources, but can't due to described problem. The error I see now is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: myapplication.module1.Module1
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:413) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:253) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:130) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at myapplication.module1.Module1.start(Module1.java:25) [classes/:?]
    at myapplication.launcher.graph.ModuleNode.start(ModuleNode.java:156) [classes/:?]
    at myapplication.launcher.graph.ModuleGraph.startModuleRecursively(ModuleGraph.java:49) [classes/:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) [?:?]
    at myapplication.launcher.graph.ModuleGraph.startAllModules(ModuleGraph.java:42) [classes/:?]
    at myapplication.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:49) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException-->module spring.core does not read module myapplication.module1
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:503) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:582) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:569) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:416) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:402) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module spring.core does not read module myapplication.module1
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(MethodHandles.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:497) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:582) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:569) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:416) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:402) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    ... 14 more
```

Question: is it possible to grant access for Spring (in fact, for `spring.core` automatic module) to classes that reside in child module layer?

Comment: The stack trace is difficult to read, seems something is filtering it to strip the module names and add source locations to the end. That said, the exception is clear that spring.core does not read myapplication.module1, you should be able to get further if you run with `--add-reads spring.core=myapplication.module1` but to fix it properly would need the code in question to add Module.addReads before calling privateLookupIn (access control with Lookup / method handles does not assume readability, unlike core reflection)

Comment: @AlanBateman yes, I understand the problem, but I don't know any workaround. I have tried to use `Module.addReads`, but of course it fails for any module except `spring.core` itself, because this operation can be done by module on itself only (as I understand).

Comment: `--add-reads spring.core=myapplication.module1` would work if application was launched directly, and anyway, it is not quite right

Comment: Also tried with ModuleLayer.Controller.addReads, but it checks that source module (spring.core) must be in created layer. Currently, I think the answer to my question is *no*.